# Variable Length vs Malloc-ed arrays

Tags: c, arrays

According to c99 standard, we can write the following code and it's totally legal

```
int x;
scanf("%d",&x);
int ar[x];
```

My question is, if I can allocate an array like this, why would I ever need malloc to allocate variable size arrays again?

Also, could you please explain how does the variable length arrays allocation happens? Deep inside, does it call malloc to allocate the array or what?

Comment: What happens if you wish to return the array from the function or store it in a structure? Object lifetime in C is ... fun.

Comment: Because the storage of a `malloc()`'d array is different, the heap.

Comment: you may be interested in this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592318/how-is-dynamic-memory-allocation-better-than-array/6592437

Comment: Possible duplicate of [malloced array VS. variable-length-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672322/malloced-array-vs-variable-length-array)

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩 This question is two years older than the question you linked.

Comment: @xci13 I go by upvote count nowadays http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two reasons spring to my mind:

1. Arrays that live beyond this stack frame.
2. Arrays that are bigger than the stack.

Comment: 3. Arrays that you can return from a function. But i guess that is included in number 1.

Comment: @hexa that's all there is to item 1

Comment: thanks for the answers, guys, it makes perfect sense now.
I still have something though, how is the variable length array implemented inside C? assuming I am using gcc compiler.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I used a bad phrase, I actually meant that.
Still, how is it implemented by the compiler? is there a simple way that you guys can explain it?
Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: I understand that it is up to the implementator to decide how to allocate variable length arrays (VLAs). I actually think variable length array is a terrible nomenclature since they never vary in size once allocated. All the same, that's what they are called.  GCC allocates them on the stack with a simple stack pointer increment.  But other implementations are free to put them on the heap if they so desire.

Comment: @Adel - It's allocated off the stack like a 'normal' array. It's not strictly a variable length array, as the length is fixed and can't be changed unlike c++ vectors. (which are basically `malloc`d)

Comment: @Roddy I agree with your sentiments 100%, but unfortunately the official term for these things is indeed variable length arrays. Go figure!

Answer (score 5):

Variable length array allocation (or any array declaration actually) is done on the stack (assuming GCC compiler).  Malloc assigns memory from the heap.

Two advantages to heap vs. stack:
1. Stack is much smaller.  There is a decent chance that your variable-size array could cause your stack to overflow.
2. Items allocated on the stack don't survive after the function they were declared in returns.

Comment: Your 'advantage' #2 is also a potential disadvantage and frequent cause of memory leaks. Arrays on the stack (used with care) are often good practice.

Answer (score 2):

In the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), variable length arrays became "optional" which I take to mean "implementation defined" and as such they are no longer portable.

This is shown in

> 6.7.6.2 Array declarators section 4
>
> Variable length arrays are a conditional feature that implementations
>   need not support.

and

> 6.10.8.3 Conditional feature macros section 1
>
> `__STDC_NO_VLA__` The integer constant 1, intended to indicate that the implementation does not support variable length arrays or variably
>   modified types.

Some advantages of using `malloc` over the **VLA** are:

- The implementation of `malloc` usually obtains memory from the
  **heap** which in most C implememtations is a bigger resource than the **stack**. However neither **heap** nor **stack** are mentioned
  in the C standard, but they are common ways to implement global and local memory.
- Memory obtained from `malloc` can be increased or reduced by
  `realloc` but it is not possible with a VLA.
- Memory obtained from `malloc` can be passed around the program until
  `free`d, with pointers, but the VLA can only be used in a hierarchy
  of functions. The VLA becomes dead after the function in which it is
  defined returns, because it goes out of scope.