# Problem with forming string array using loop

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I want to create a string array using loop inputs and then give ASCII based output for each character of the string.

Here is my code

```cpp
int n;
cin >> n;
string arr[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
    getline(cin,arr[i]);
}
for(int i = 0;i < n; ++i){
    for(int j = 0;j < arr[i].length(); ++j){
        cout << to_string(arr[i].at(j)) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

the program takes `n` : number of string inputs
but allows me to input only `n-1` strings.

What is the problem here?

Comment: What do you mean? what the `arr` is? a list of strings?

Comment: every string in c++ has a special character at the end which is automatically put by the compiler  i.e. ϕ (Phi)

Comment: I want to create an array of strings, consisting of 'n' members.

Comment: `cin>>n;   string arr[n];` is not valid in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading `n` strings, but the first one doesn't contain what you expect.

When you write input in the console, you write something like:

```
3\nstring1\nstring2
```

, where `\n` is the newline character (when you press Enter).

When you do `cin >> n`, you parse this input string, and you get the integer. Meaning that you remain with

```
\nstring1\nstring2
```

in the buffer. And when you do a `getline`, you parse everything up to the first newline (including the newline). That's why you get the first string empty.

A quick and dirty fix is to read the newline too:

```
int n;
char newline;
cin >> n >> newline;
```

, and then loop as you do now.

---

Some remarks about your code.

`string arr[n]` is not valid C++. In C++, there is no official support for arrays with variable size like this (some compilers support it, but this doesn't mean it's standard). You should use a `std::vector`:

`std::vector<std::string> arr(n);`

(the rest of the code remains the same). An even better way would be to declare it empty, and then use `push_back` to populate it.

Also, when comparing `j < arr[i].length()`, you are comparing a variable of type `int` with a variable of type `size_t`, which might be bigger than an `int` and create issues for very long strings. Use `size_t` as the type for j.

Comment: `std::array<std::string> arr(n);` is completely wrong. You need to provide the length of the array at compile time.

Comment: @Adrian That would change behavior of the program. With `getline` "Hello world, how are you\n" would be one string, with `>>` that would be five strings.

Comment: I am using getline because I am inputting strings having spaces

Comment: @GameX Oops! I was thinking out-of-space!

Comment: Here is my input:2
hellomecian
MelCow

.     The program is not reading the very first letter of the first string , that is, `h`. The rest is fine. Does this has to do something with getline as well?

Comment: @GameX Try inserting a newline after 2.

Answer (score 1):

### Use a std::vector

A vector is dynamic array. So change:

```
string arr[n];
```

to

```
std::vector<std::string> arr(n);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code snippet what you want to read is a number of strings and then output for each of them the ASCII value of all of its characters:

If you have an input like the following

```
2
abc
def
```

you would like to obtains as a result something like the following:

```
97 98 99 
100 101 102
```

In order to achieve that I see at least a couple of problems with your code.

1. C++ does not support variable size arrays by default. It means you cannot create an array whose size is not known at compile time (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672322/malloced-array-vs-variable-length-array) for more info about it)
2. In order to output the ASCII of the char you simply need to cast the `char` to `int` and that is it.
3. using `getline` in this case complicates the code because of the way `getline` works with newline. Simply use `cin>>arr[i]` to read each string.

Here is it a version of your code that does what you expect:

```
int n;
   cin>>n;
   vector<string> arr(n);

   for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
        cin>>arr[i];

    for(const auto& s : arr){
        for(const auto& c : s){
            cout<<(int)c<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a list of strings, you can use `vector`:

```cpp
#include<vector>
#include<string>

int n;
cin >> n;
vector<string> arr(n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    getline(cin, arr[i]);
}
for(auto& str : arr){
    for(auto& c : str){
        cout << to_string(c) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```